# How to display that the shopping cart is empty - Flask

Tags: python, flask, cart, webshop

I am creating a webshop using Flask. For the moment, I am trying to display a message when the shopping cart is empty. I have already managed to display the message when the amount of 0 of a product is added to the cart, using an if-test. But I fail to display a message when no amount of the product is added to the cart (the bold piece of code (between *) is where the error message appears)).

This is my route function in Python:

```
@app.route('/cart', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def cart():
    product_id = session['product_id']
    product = my_products[product_id]
    totalprice = int(session['amount']) * product['price']
    return render_template('cart.html', product=product, totalprice=totalprice)
```

This is my html-file of the cart (cart.html):

```
{% if session['amount'] == '0' or **product_id == None** %}

<p>You have no products in your cart.</p>

<div id="place_order">
    <button id='btnalert' disabled>place order</button>
</div>

{% else %}

<p>You have in your cart:</p>
<p>Product: {{product['name']}}</p>
<p>Price: {{product['price']}}</p>
<p>Amount: {{session['amount']}}</p>

<p id="totalprice">TOTAL PRICE: {{totalprice}}</p>

<div id="place_order">
<button id='btnalert'>place order</button>

<script>
    btnAlert = document.querySelector('#btnalert')

    function showAlert() {
        alert('Sorry, this shop is out of business!')
    }

    btnAlert.addEventListener("click", showAlert)
</script>
</div>

{% endif %}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you share what the error message says?

Comment: It just gives a 500 Internal Server Error saying "The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application." When I look in the terminal, it says "KeyError: 'product_id' "

Answer (score 0):

What if you pass the product_id as a variable as well.

try this :

> return render_template('cart.html', product=product, product_id=product_id ,totalprice=totalprice)

and modify this line:

> {% if session['amount'] == '0' or {{product_id}} == None %}

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, I still get the same error :/

Comment: shouldn't None be str ( 'None') ?